# Zend DB select with literal

Tags: php, zend-db

I have a sql statement with a union between two tables. For simplicity lets say that table A has a column called `columnA` and table B has a column called `cloumnB`. Since table A doesn't have a `columnB` in it and vice-versa, I want to place a static value for the records from table A in the union, something like this

```
$select->from ( array (
                'A' => 'tableA' 
        ), array (
                'id',
                'column1',
                .....
                'columnB' => "'nonExistingValue'",
                .....
        ) )
```

The problem is that Zend is searching for a column called `nonExistingValue` instead of treating it as a string literal. How can I make Zend treat this as a literal?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working it around like this:

```
$select->from ( array (
                'A' => 'tableA' 
        ), array (
                'id',
                'column1',
                .....
                'columnB' => "CONCAT('n','onExistingValue')",
                .....
        ) )
```